# Rails groupdate gem: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "warehouse_campaigns.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using the groupdate gem: https://github.com/ankane/groupdate

I'm simply using 'group_by_day_of_week', and attempting to output the results, and get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "warehouse_campaigns.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Here's the code:

```
@campaigns = WarehouseCampaign.group_by_day_of_week(:date_sent)
```

Then in HAML:

```
  - @campaigns.each do |r|
    = r.title
```

Note, I DO NOT want simply the count of records, I want to list the actual records for each group. I've searched for an hour for a solution to this. Is this specific to postgres?

Comment: Can you provide an actual SQL query from logs?

Comment: GROUP BY isn't for chunking things, it is (mostly) for feeding groups of rows into aggregate functions. Perhaps you're really looking to order things by the day of the week instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can get aggregation counts with  groupdate gem with the mentioned query. If you want to group records based on the day of week value, you will have to fire DB query accordingly.

```
@campaigns = WarehouseCampaign.all.group_by { |x| x.date_sent.wday }
```

This will group the records based on the day of week number([wday](https://apidock.com/ruby/Date/wday)) and you can iterate over records.

If you just want to get the aggregation count, you can simply do this,

```
@counts = WarehouseCampaign.group("EXTRACT(DOW FROM date_sent)").count
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: When you say "with the mentioned query.", with query are you referring to? I'm getting an error as described in my original post.

Comment: I was referring to this `@campaigns = WarehouseCampaign.group_by_day_of_week(:date_sent)` query. This will work if you take counts on it like : `@campaigns = WarehouseCampaign.group_by_day_of_week(:date_sent).count`. Otherwise you will have to use group_by separately to get all the records